# Recursive function in Redux/Thunk returning Promise object, not regular object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm calling a function from an action creator:

`getPostComments(author, permlink)
        .then(comments => {...`

That functions is called recursively as well to get all the  nested comments:

```
const getPostComments = (author, permlink) => {
  return client.database.call('get_content_replies', [author, permlink])
    .then(replies => {
      return replies.map(r => {
        if (r.children > 0) {
          return getPostComments(r.author, r.permlink)
            .then(children => children)
            .then(unpromised => {
              r.replies = unpromised
              return r;
            })
        }else {
          return r;
        }
      });
    });
}
```

The problem is, that first call is returned with a Promise object. For example, a page has 3 comments, and one of them has a nested comment. The comments without nested comments return the comment object, while the comment which has nesting returns Promise object.

[image]

[image]

0: is a comment with a comment.
1: is a comment alone.
2: is a comment alone.

The nested comment within it (0:) is returned as a regular object since I do a `.then(unpromised => {` on it to resolve the recursive call to `getPostComments`.

[image]

But the first call to `getPostComments` is a Promise object (as shown in the first 2 images), and I want regular data object, not a Promise object.

How can I make it a regular object? What is going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your issue is just that you're not waiting for the promises from the `map` to resolve. `Promise.all` should fix it I think (untested).

```
const getPostComments = (author, permlink) => {
  return client.database.call('get_content_replies', [author, permlink])
    .then(replies => Promise.all(replies.map(r => {
      if (r.children > 0) {
        return getPostComments(r.author, r.permlink)
          .then(comments => {
            r.replies = comments
            return r;
          })
      } else {
        return r;
      }
    })));
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for helping this newb :D